# Decompressing large zst files

Tags: windows, zip, compression, archive, zstandard

I have a 16gb compressed zst file. how would I decompress it on windows? I do not have the memory to handle the decompressed version, so it needs to be written straight to a file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the risk of sounding obvious, you need a windows decompressor that supports zstandard.

At the [zstandard releases page](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases), there are two prebuilt Windows executables, [zstd-v1.5.5-win32.zip](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases/download/v1.5.5/zstd-v1.5.5-win32.zip) and [zstd-v1.5.5-win64.zip](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases/download/v1.5.5/zstd-v1.5.5-win64.zip) available.

Regarding the amount of memory needed, zstandard will *not* decompress it completely into memory before writing to the filesystem -- it works in a  *streaming mode* loop that operates like this pseudo-code

```
WHILE NOT at eof of zstd file
    read a small part of the compressed data into memory
    uncompressing it into memory
    writes the uncompressed data to disk
```

Comment: When you have the zstd.exe, you can decompress a file usign the following command: zstd -d path/to/your/filename.zst