# Alternate Methods For Working with ZST Files in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programing language.

I have large .ZST files on my computer that I want to import in to R Studio (e.g. https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/).

I found this library in R https://github.com/thekvs/zstdr - but apparently this library is not available for Windows and is very difficult to install.

I tried looking online, but there really does not seem to be any other way to work with these .ZST files.

**Can someone please show me a way in R to import and work with these .ZST files without downloading this library? Is there some direct way to do this while working "natively" in R?**

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps using [zst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675707/decompressing-large-zst-files), and note streaming as may be necessary depending on uncompressed file size and your available ram.

Comment: Thank you @Chris! I was hoping to find something that could run locally in R ...